# How to call a fragment from a class

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

I just want to call fragment from this class.
Actually i have many fragments in my app and have to call them again and again.
So i thought to make a class and a function for loading a fragment so whenever i need to call a fragment i can use the function of this class.
But iam unable to get **getSupportFragmentManager()** here.
I tried by extending the class to fragment but then it produces null exception.
also by extending with Appcompactactivity and uses **getSupportFragmentManager();** but is also gives error by saying the activity destroyed.
So anyone have solution to call a fragment from a simple class?

```
public class CompletedandPendingScreensLoader {


public void pendingscreenLoader(int serialnumber){
    Fragment frag = null;

    switch (serialnumber){
        case 1:
            frag = new LessonOne();
            break;

        case 2:
            frag = new LessonTwo();
            break;
        case 3:
            frag = new LessonThree();
            break;
        case 4:
            frag = new LessonFour();
            break;
        case 5:
            frag = new LessonFive();
            break;

    }
    if (frag != null) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("pending","pen");
        frag.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame, frag).addToBackStack(null); // replace a Fragment with Frame Layout
        transaction.commit(); // commit the changes

    }

}



public void completedscreenLoader(int serialnumber){
    Fragment frag = null;

    switch (serialnumber){
        case 1:
            frag = new LessonOne();
            break;

        case 2:
            frag = new LessonTwo();
            break;
        case 3:
            frag = new LessonThree();
            break;
        case 4:
            frag = new LessonFour();
            break;
        case 5:
            frag = new LessonFive();
            break;

    }
    if (frag != null) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("completed","yes");
        frag.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame, frag).addToBackStack(null); // replace a Fragment with Frame Layout
        transaction.commit(); // commit the changes

    }

}

public void simpleScreenLoader( int serialnumber){

    Fragment frag = null;

    switch (serialnumber){
        case 1:
            frag = new LessonOne();
            break;
        case 2:
            frag = new LessonTwo();
            break;
        case 3:
            frag = new LessonThree();
            break;
        case 4:
            frag = new LessonFour();
            break;
        case 5:
            frag = new LessonFive();
            break;

    }
    if (frag != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame, new LessonTwo()).addToBackStack(null); // replace a Fragment with Frame Layout
        transaction.commit();






    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will at some point call this class from some **activity** or **fragment** if so then use the modified constructor it will open the fragment. else you can't do it without having a **reference** for **FragmentManager** from activity or fragment.

```
  public class CompletedandPendingScreensLoader {
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager = null;

    //when ever you start your class just start using this constructor 
    CompletedandPendingScreensLoader(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
       this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager
    }


    public void pendingscreenLoader(int serialnumber){
        Fragment frag = null;

        switch (serialnumber){
            case 1:
                frag = new LessonOne();
                break;

            case 2:
                frag = new LessonTwo();
                break;
            case 3:
                frag = new LessonThree();
                break;
            case 4:
                frag = new LessonFour();
                break;
            case 5:
                frag = new LessonFive();
                break;

        }
        if (frag != null) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("pending","pen");
            frag.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame, frag).addToBackStack(null); // replace a Fragment with Frame Layout
            transaction.commit(); // commit the changes

        }

    }



    public void completedscreenLoader(int serialnumber){
        Fragment frag = null;

        switch (serialnumber){
            case 1:
                frag = new LessonOne();
                break;

            case 2:
                frag = new LessonTwo();
                break;
            case 3:
                frag = new LessonThree();
                break;
            case 4:
                frag = new LessonFour();
                break;
            case 5:
                frag = new LessonFive();
                break;

        }
        if (frag != null) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("completed","yes");
            frag.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame, frag).addToBackStack(null); // replace a Fragment with Frame Layout
            transaction.commit(); // commit the changes

        }

    }

    public void simpleScreenLoader( int serialnumber){

        Fragment frag = null;

        switch (serialnumber){
            case 1:
                frag = new LessonOne();
                break;
            case 2:
                frag = new LessonTwo();
                break;
            case 3:
                frag = new LessonThree();
                break;
            case 4:
                frag = new LessonFour();
                break;
            case 5:
                frag = new LessonFive();
                break;

        }
        if (frag != null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame, new LessonTwo()).addToBackStack(null); // replace a Fragment with Frame Layout
            transaction.commit();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class must extend **AppCompatActivity** class to call this function, and when you extend the class then you have to also override **onCreate()** method of the activity and you have to also set Layout for the activity in onCreate() Method

```
public class CompletedandPendingScreensLoader {

 private AppCompatActivity myActivty;

 public CompletedandPendingScreensLoader(AppCompatAcitivity myActivty)
 {
     this.myActivity = myActivity
   }


public void pendingscreenLoader(int serialnumber){
Fragment frag = null;

switch (serialnumber){
    case 1:
        frag = new LessonOne();
        break;

    case 2:
        frag = new LessonTwo();
        break;
    case 3:
        frag = new LessonThree();
        break;
    case 4:
        frag = new LessonFour();
        break;
    case 5:
        frag = new LessonFive();
        break;

}
if (frag != null) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("pending","pen");
    frag.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = 
    myActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame, frag).addToBackStack(null); // replace a Fragment with Frame Layout
    transaction.commit(); // commit the changes

}

  }



public void completedscreenLoader(int serialnumber){
Fragment frag = null;

switch (serialnumber){
    case 1:
        frag = new LessonOne();
        break;

    case 2:
        frag = new LessonTwo();
        break;
    case 3:
        frag = new LessonThree();
        break;
    case 4:
        frag = new LessonFour();
        break;
    case 5:
        frag = new LessonFive();
        break;

}
if (frag != null) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("completed","yes");
    frag.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = 
    myAcitvity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame, frag).addToBackStack(null); // replace a Fragment with Frame Layout
    transaction.commit(); // commit the changes

}

}

 public void simpleScreenLoader( int serialnumber){

Fragment frag = null;

switch (serialnumber){
    case 1:
        frag = new LessonOne();
        break;
    case 2:
        frag = new LessonTwo();
        break;
    case 3:
        frag = new LessonThree();
        break;
    case 4:
        frag = new LessonFour();
        break;
    case 5:
        frag = new LessonFive();
        break;

}
if (frag != null) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = 
     myActivity.getFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame, new LessonTwo()).addToBackStack(null); // replace a Fragment with Frame Layout
    transaction.commit();






}
}
```

Comment: but i dont need that ... i just want to use the functions of this class without making it activity.

Comment: Then you can make an instance of AppCompatActivity Class in the your class and intitalize it in the constructor of your class and then from that object of appCompatActivity you can call the functions

Comment: can you explain it by a code example ... because i didn't understand you

Comment: ok i got that ... but what to pass in the object parameters for appcompatactivity while making its object in fragment ?

CompletedandPendingScreensLoader screensLoader = new CompletedandPendingScreensLoader(---what to pass here ---);

Comment: If you make an object of this class in an activity pass "this" , if you are making object of this in a fragment pass "getActivty()" .